# Javascript alert problem

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to add an alert box so that the user can choose either Yes or No or Ok and Cancel, but it is not working correctly.I have to do a database check which is done in c sharp not just link that function to a button clicked event.  It is my first time I am trying to do this. I am using visual studio 2010. I am not sure if my code is correct. Can anyone please guide me if I am mistaken.

```
         private void AlertWithConfirmation()
           {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>"); 
            Response.Write("function onsub() "); 
            Response.Write("{ "); 
            Response.Write("return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")"); 
            Response.Write("} "); 
            Response.Write("</script>");
           }
```

This is my full C# Code:

```
    protected void Import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Validation.ValidateDateFormat(dateField.Text))
        {
            errorMessageLabel.Text = "Invalid Date Format, for example: 1/1/2011 should be 01/01/2011";
        }
        else
        {
            //Validation to check if data is already imported
            if (BusinessLayerHandler.isImported(dateField.Text) == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (BusinessLayerHandler.isInProgress(dateField.Text)== true)
                    {
                        AlertWithConfirmation();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //catch error
                }
            }
            else if (BusinessLayerHandler.isImported(dateField.Text) == true)
            {
                Alert("That date was already imported");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're mistaken, this code is pretty meaningless. What is your goal exactly? What are you trying to prevent if user click the Cancel button?

Comment: Did you tried a semicolon after your confirm?

Comment: You're writing the function to the page but where are you triggering the function? There are other ways I think this should be done however given your example, it seems like you want the onsub method to fire when the page re-loads, in which case you'll want to attach it to the documents onload eveent.

Comment: Have you tried not to wrap it in a function?

Comment: have you tried calling the function ^_^

Comment: @ Jamie Dixon ....I only want the alert box to pop up if the data is being imported.

Comment: You'll need to do this with an AJAX call, or multiple post backs. Writing to the response isn't going to make the browser execute your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

your code is absolutely correct. only syntax error. just remove "\" before starting the double quotes in the line->
Response.Write("return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")");
replace with this line
Response.Write("return confirm("Are you sure?\")");

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're calling the function.  Why not have the function always on the page and dynamically add the function call to the button in the code behind?

Something like:

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onsub();");
```

Comment: @ giovanni galbo.... i am calling it on page load:protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AlertWithConfirmation();
        }

Comment: That's not calling the javascript function... it's calling the code that writes a javascript function.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. is this the javascript function? private void AlertWithConfirmation()            {             Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>");              Response.Write("function onsub() ");              Response.Write("{ ");              Response.Write("return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")");              Response.Write("} ");              Response.Write("</script>");            }

Comment: That's the function, but you need javascript code to call the function.